# How to use ssh-keyscan with golang:alpine Docker image?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to create a Dockerfile using `golang:alpine` image and ssh-keyscan command, but it is not working. If I use the `golang` image instead, it works as expected.

Works:

```
FROM golang

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN git config --add --global url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/

WORKDIR /app

ENV GOPRIVATE=github.com/{ommited}/*

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN --mount=type=ssh go mod download
```

Does not work:

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN git config --add --global url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/

WORKDIR /app

ENV GOPRIVATE=github.com/{ommited}/*

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN --mount=type=ssh go mod download
```

Error:

> [9/9] RUN --mount=type=ssh go mod download:
> #13 32.30 go: {ommited}@v0.9.3: reading {ommited}/go.mod at revision v0.9.3: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/4dc358100530ae5178fe8ee87660554544c37849403335a46d005c2394bf07a5: exit status 128:
> #13 32.30   git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> #13 32.30   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> #13 32.30
> #13 32.30   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> #13 32.30   and the repository exists.

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download]: exit code: 1

Comment: To clarify, is the goal here to build a go image which depends on modules inside of a private github repo?

Comment: @NickODell Yes, that's the goal. And I don´t want to need to specify paths of local rsa keys or any credentials in the Dockerfile.

Comment: What type of SSH key do you use? Are you running into this problem with RSA keys? https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/222

Comment: @NickODell I use RSA keys.

Comment: How you build both images is missing, as is the content of go.mod and go.sum. Further, you're using `~/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh`, are those supposed to be the same? What versions of Git and OpenSSH are getting installed in the two. That said, checking bug tickets is a good advise from Nick!

Comment: _git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)_ > You are denied on that repository with your public key, so it is not an issue with Alpine but with your private key.